# Saving Image from a picture box ,image was drawn by graphics object

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, picturebox

I have this code throwing exception on "pictureBox2.Image.Save(st + "patch1.jpg");" I think there is nothing saved on pictureBox2.Image ,But I have created graphics g on it.
how do I save the image of pictureBox2.Image?

```
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Graphics g = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height),rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        sourceBitmap.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        //MessageBox.Show(path);
        string st = path + "/Debug";
        MessageBox.Show(st);
        pictureBox2.Image.Save(st + "patch1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems.

First, CreateGraphics is a temporary drawing surface, not suitable for saving anything.  I suspect you want to actually create a new image and display it in the second PictureBox:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap)) {
  g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
pictureBox2.Image = newBitmap;
```

Secondly, use the Path.Combine function to create your file string:

```
string file = Path.Combine(new string[] { Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Debug", "patch1.jpg" });
newBitmap.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

That path has to exist or else the Save method will throw a GDI+ exception.

Comment: I might be 3 years after OP, but thank you for an answer that took me hours to find.

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics g = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();`

You should read up the documentation on this method you are calling, it's not at all what you want.  It's for painting to a control outside of OnPaint, which is bad practice and will get overwritten by the next OnPaint, AND it has nothing to do with the `PictureBox.Image` property, absolutely nothing.

What are you actually trying to do?  You want to save a crop of an image which is displayed in a PictureBox control?  Do you need to have a preview of the crop operation before you save it to disk?  Do you need to update this preview when the crop rectangle changes?  Provide some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way round. Create a destination bitmap and a Graphics instance for that bitmap. Then copy the source picturebox image into that bitmap. Finally, assign that bitmap to the second picture box

```
Rectangle rectCropArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
Bitmap destBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap);
g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
g.Dispose();
pictureBox2.Image = destBitmap;
pictureBox2.Image.Save(@"c:\temp\patch1.jpg");
```